# Drawing Multiple lines in pcl with known model coefficients

Tags: c++, lines, point-cloud-library, coefficients

I have extracted segments from a point cloud and and  used `pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ> seg;`  to fit all the lines simultaneously. All my file segments are stored in the same folder, and I'm able to read them one by one and calculate their model coefficients individually.

The best way to get around this problem is through a `for` loop, but `viewer.addLine` gives errors on the second iteration saying that `addLine` has already been used after drawing one line (RANSAC). I have used the method from the PCL site http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cylinder_segmentation.php to determine the coefficients of all my segments. According to what I have learned so far, the model coefficients are stored internally.

Goal: Draw all the lines from the model coefficients simultaneously using RANSAC and add them to the PCL visualizer.

This is the snippet I used to load the all the files (example)

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "./cloud_cluster_" << j << ".pcd";
reader.read<pcl::PointXYZ> (ss.str (), *cloud_cluster, false); 
j++;

// snip

pcl::visualizer viewer ("Sample programme")
viewer.addCloud();
viewer.addLine(model_coefficients)
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `addLine` function that you are using is documented in the API here:
http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html#a5fd2b99b85da61df8b58980bdb6b0f41

The signature:

```
bool addLine (const pcl::ModelCoefficients &coefficients, const std::string &id="line", int viewport=0)
```

Here you can see that when you add a line, it is automatically given a string id "`line`". This is fine if you add only one line but for multiple lines you need to give a unique id for each line.

e.g.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss<<"line"<<j;
viewer.addLine(model_coefficients,ss.str());
```